# How do games go about adding x gold per hour without straining the db?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm working on a little project to learn Javascript that is kind of like any typical browser-based strategy game. It uses php 5.3.x, MySQL, and Javacript/jQuery.

I was able to successfully check and update every hour on the hour using MySQL Events the user's kingdom gold from their rate that it increases per hour. For example, if it's 50Gold/Hour and the User has 0, in an hour the user will have 50.

The problem with this, is that it updates only once per hour, and I can't wrap my mind around a way to make it so that it updates every time the user should get new gold (ie: 60seconds/hr gold). So if the player is making 60 Gold per hour, then every min, the user's gold should update with +1/min. If they are making 60,000Gold/hr then +16/min (but it would actually be 16.6666...?).

This seems like it would be easy to do using a simple Javascript code that assumes how much you're making but if you were to say, refresh, it wouldn't know you had that gold because in the database it would show differently. Also it wouldn't let the user buy anything like a farm upgrade because it would fail validation.

Any ideas would be helpful on how to make this work? Scanning / Updating every second doesn't seem like a good idea and it doesn't seem like the right way to go.

Thank you!

**EDIT -- RESOLVED --:**
Okay so I got it working after spending a good hour or so on it. It was pretty easy. Here's what I did thank to Cereal's idea...

- Got rid of MySQL event to auto-update
- Users have "last event" sessions, so if they refresh or go to the map, it's considered an event. Same with opening the buy/upgrade thing.
- When an event as such is triggered, it checks the last event and current time (local of server). It does the math and returns a decimal if needed and updates last event. So basically if you were playing for 10 minutes since your last "triggered" event, and you're earning 60 Gold per hour, it will calculate that you earned 10 Gold and update the db accordingly. If it's a decimal, it will round and update. There is a loss but it's insignificant for my purpose.
- Javascript takes care of the rest for assuming what you should have visually.

I hope this makes sense for anyone looking to do something similar. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could eliminate scheduled events for something like this, and just use some simple math.

For instance, let's say the user is gaining 16 gold every minute. Client side, you could obviously implement it to auto-increment every minute. As for when they return from a break, you could calculate the gold from their last visited time (say, June 16th, 8:02am). So, the next time they/someone views their gold, you could take the last visited time, and the current time, and calculate the amount of gold to add.

Example: If the next time the gold is accessed is June 16th, 8:10am, you would add 128 gold, and adjust the last visited time, etc.

Comment: Thank you! That's a really good idea. I'll think on what you said and figure something out but your answer is sending me into the right direction. :) I'd upvote you but the crazy amount of downvotes just now made it impossible.